# When uninstalling Angular CLI (@angular/cli) the angular version is still 6.2.0

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6, angular-cli-v7

I'm trying to update my angular-cli version to the latest, and for that I'm doing:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
```

After that, I closed and opened again the terminal and typed in an empty folder:

```
ng -v
```

and the output was: 6.2.0

I also tried to install the latest version of angular with:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and then executing

```
ng new my-app
```

but the next error showed:

```
npm ERR! path /home/<path>/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/raul/<path>/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/<my_name>/.npm/_logs/2018-11-09T23_58_11_085Z-debug.log
```

And inside that log I have:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ng',
1 verbose cli   'new',
1 verbose cli   'my-app' ]
2 info using npm@6.2.0
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/<path>r/package.json'
5 verbose cwd /home/<path>
6 verbose Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
7 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ng" "new" "my-app"
8 verbose node v10.13.0
9 verbose npm  v6.2.0
10 error path /home/<path>/package.json
11 error code ENOENT
12 error errno -2
13 error syscall open
14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home<path>/package.json'
15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
16 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

I also tried doing "ng serve" on an existing project and it worked fine.

Comment: Try `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was my bad, in my .bashrc i redirected "ng" to "npm use ng".

Sorry and thank you all

Answer (score 0):

try the code below in new empty dir.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng v
```

Comment: I tried and just after "npm cache verify" i tried  "ng -v" and the output was still "6.2.0"

After all these instructions, the output for "ng -v" is still 6.2.0

Comment: Also, i just realized that "ng -v" is outputing my npm version, so i guess at some point I redirected the command "ng" to "npm"